# Fetching review value using wpdb class

Tags: php, wpdb, sql, plugin-gd-star-rating, xml

I'm generating an XML file using PHP for a website where they review tech products. In the XML file, I have to display the rating of products. For rating purposes, I'm using GD Star Rating plugin.

I've been experimenting with wpdb class to fetch the rating of each product. However I've not had any luck so far. I'm using the following SQL code on phpmyadmin and I'm able to to fetch the rating for any product review I want

```
SELECT review FROM tableName_gdsr_data_article WHERE post_id = 4627
```

But when I try this SQL code in PHP, as seen below, all I get is bunch of errors.

```
$post_id = $post->ID;
$reviewScore = $wpdb->query(
    $wpdb->prepare( 
    "SELECT review FROM tableName_gdsr_data_article WHERE post_id = '$post_id'"
    )
);
```

Does anyone have any idea why the code above doesn't work? Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you give an example of one or some of the errors?

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the global $wpdb reference and also add the second parameter required for prepare():

```
global $wpdb;
$post_id = $post->ID;
$reviewScore = $wpdb->query(
    $wpdb->prepare( 
        "SELECT review FROM {$wpdb->prefix}gdsr_data_article WHERE post_id = %d",
        $post_id
    )
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Oh, you'll kick yourself for this one.

You have:

`$wpbd->prepare`

Should be:

`$wpdb->prepare`

Simple typo :)

Comment: Ouch! that hurts :)
Corrected the typo error but still getting an error. Here is error I get

`Fatal error: Call to a member function query() on a non-object in...`

The error points to the line

`$reviewScore = $wpdb->query`

Comment: You need to call `global $wpdb;` somewhere above that query.

Comment: Adding `global $wpdb;`eliminated the fatal error. Thanks for that. But still the rating value is not returned. Instead it prints out the text `Array` in xml file. I guess the post ID is not properly passed into the query. Do you think that is the case? Thanks for the all help again.

Comment: Well the code you showed above assumes that you have the `$post` object, and therefore can get the post ID via `$post->ID`. But if you had to call `$wpdb` then you probably don't have the `$post` object and you can call it the same way (i.e. `$global $wpdb, $post;`). That will get the ID of the page/post you are currently on.

Comment: Unfortunately, that didn't solve the problem as well. But here is the full code I'm working on - http://pastebin.com/139mGqAw Maybe this will be of some help. Thanks again.

Comment: On your `SELECT` line you should be using `$post->ID`. You should also try putting an actual post ID in there to see if that works.

Comment: I finally figured out how to get the review value. Here's the updated SQL

`global $wpdb, $post;
$prefix = $wpdb->prefix; 
....
$reviewScore = $wpdb->get_var(
    $wpdb->prepare(
    "
    SELECT review
    FROM ". $prefix ."gdsr_data_article
    WHERE post_id = ".$post_id."
    "
    )
);`
Thanks @developdaly once again for your help. It's much appreciated!